# Create a beta package adding a post install script using Salesforce DX

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Is there anyway to specify (using Salesforce DX) that the package I want to create includes a post install script?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package1.htm#cli_reference_force_package1

I don't see any parameters in the command to include it. If you create it manually it works fine, but just was wondering if it is a missed feature in Salesforce DX cli.

Answer (score 1):

The postinstall script is set as part of the `package.xml` file, which if you're using SFDX for development you'll probably be automatically generating as part of your build script using `sfdx force:source:convert`.

We use a tool in our build runner called xmlstarlet which we use to inject the postInstallClass script name into the `package.xml` file before it is deployed to the packaging org and the package is created.

```
xml ed --inplace -N sfdc="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" \
       --subnode "/sfdc:Package" --type elem -n "postInstallClass" -v "PostInstall" \
       ./mdapi-source/package.xml
```

This adds the following element to the `package.xml`

```
<postInstallClass>PostInstall</postInstallClass>
```

Alternatively you could do this using a find and replace tool like `sed` or by maintaining the `package.xml` in source.

An [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/3) has been logged against the CLI to allow this and other package related attributes (uninstall script, release notes link etc.) to be specified in the `force:source:convert` command.

Comment: Thanks - this is a great tip. We needed something ideally without any external tools, so I'm using the following in our windows based script (bit of a bodge but works well enough for us): `powershell -Command "(gc mdapi_output_dir/package.xml) -replace '</Package>', '<postInstallClass>PostInstallScript</postInstallClass></Package>' | Out-File -encoding UTF8 mdapi_output_dir/package.xml"`. Linux based would of course be trivial using sed.